# I want to retrieve an Image from database and crop it as per the user needs

Tags: c#, asp.net, image-processing

i want to crop a photo retrieved from database, i have done the following to retrieve the image from the database

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=card;User Id=sa;Password=db2admin;");
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select Photo from iffcar", connection);
        byte[] image = (byte[])command.ExecuteScalar();
        stream.Write(image, 0, image.Length);
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(stream);
        Response.ContentType = "image/gif";
        bitmap.Save(Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
    catch (Exception ee)
    {
        connection.Close();
        stream.Close(); 
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(ee.Message);
    }
}
```

The image that is retrieved is displayed inside the browser.

Now i am stuck at how to crop this image,i want to allow the user to crop the image retrieved from the database and store the cropped image to be passed onto crystal report.

Is this possible? If so than is there any tutorial or help which would guide me to my end requirement.please help me to understand how to proceed with my query

Comment: maybe you should have a look at this project:http://code.google.com/p/jcrop/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fill in the ??s and try this:

```
    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select Photo from iffcar", connection);
    byte[] image = (byte[])command.ExecuteScalar();
    stream.Write(image, 0, image.Length);
    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(stream);

    int croppedWidth = ??, croppedHeight = ??, cropOffsetX = ??, cropOffsetY = ??;
    var croppedBitmap = new Bitmap(croppedWidth, croppedHeight);
    var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(croppedBitmap);
    graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, -cropOffsetX, -cropOffsetY, bitmap.Width, bitmap .Height);
    Response.ContentType = "image/gif";
    croppedBitmap.Save(Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Comment: if it dont Crop the image then i mis understood the question, i thought that it will,but how ever your MINUS 1 ;(

Comment: that did not help, i am getting the original image.

Comment: Should work. What values are you setting for each of the variables?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at GDI+ libraries and also the System.Drawing namespace. You can also use Windows Imaging Components.

[Here's a basic walk-through](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-image/ASPImaging1.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Yo can easyly resize image with Bitmap class, look at this constructor - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0wh0045z.aspx